# What is nuget props file and what is it for?

Tags: nuget, properties-file, nuget-spec

I have looked around and read a lot but couldn't find a definitive answer that would explain as to what the "nuget.props" file is and what is it used for.

Any explanation and maybe with some example?

Comment: Do you mean `nuget.g.props`, or did you find a `nuget.props` somewhere? if so, where?

Comment: nuget.props file is the Package.props file which can be included in a nuget package when building a package

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Starting with some background information, .NET projects are built with MSBuild. A C# project's `.csproj` is just a MSBuild project file with a file extension that signals by convention that it's C# and not some other language, but to MSBuild it's just a project file. MSBuild has only a few base types, properties, items, targets and tasks. By convention, properties and items go in files with extension `.props`, while tasks and targets go in files ending in `.targets`. That's why if you look at old-style `csproj` files you'll see `<Import Project="path\to\Microsoft.Common.CSharp.props" />` and `<Import Project="path\to\Microsoft.Common.CSharp.targets" />`. New, SDK style projects is [basically syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2017) to do exactly the same thing.

Next, the MSBuild and .NET teams made the build system extensible. So, rather than being limited to what Microsoft built into the C# compiler/build system, you can replace parts of the build system, or add additional things into it. Without NuGet, the way to do this is to create your own `.props` and `.targets` file somewhere, then edit your `.csproj` and add `<Import ... />` statements. This can work fine if your props and targets are in the same source code repository as what's using it, but editing your csproj and hardcoding the path to the `props` and `targets` files doesn't work so well otherwise.

NuGet can help with this. If you create a package with the [appropriate conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), NuGet will make sure the props and targets are discovered and used in the build. With projects using `packages.config`, NuGet will edit the `csproj` for you on install/upgrade/uninstall. Projects using `PackageReference`, NuGet will write a file to the intermediate directory (`obj/` folder) named `nuget.g.props` and `nuget.g.targets`, which imports all the `props` and `targets` files from all the referenced NuGet packages, and the build system uses these files.

The first example I could think of why someone would want to do this is if you want to use a newer version of the .NET compiler than is installed on your system. Simply reference the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) package, and the `.props` and `.targets` in the package will replace the compile targets/tasks in the system-installed build system, and use the one from the package instead. This allows you to use new language features before the compiler is installed on your system, or if you want to make sure all builds of your code use the same compiler, even if different developers or CI agents have different versions of things installed.

Another example may be pre-compiled scripts. If you have your own scripting language, create build tools that converts them into C# files, then write MSBuild props and targets that will run before the "real build" to convert your custom language into C#, save the generated `.cs` files into the intermediate folder, add MSBuild Compile items for these generated files, then the C# compiler will compile it with all the other `.cs` files in the project. You'll need a reasonable amount of knowledge of MSBuild and the .NET build system, but it's possible.

Comment: Are .props files supported by VS2022/.Net6 project files? I have a .Net4.x solution that references a NuGet package which includes a .props file, and this works fine. After migrating the solution to .Net6 (and using the same NuGet package), the props file seems to be ignored.

Comment: Yes, it's how packages like git versioning and sourcelink work.  If you migrated from packages.config to PackageReference, something to note is that a packages `build/` files will only be imported for "direct" packages (those defined by PackageReference). Transitive packages will not import `build/` files. However, the package author can put their files in `buildTransitive/` instead (not well documented, but it is technically documented), so that both transitive and direct references use it. `buildTransitive` is not supported by packages.config, so supporting both styles gets complex.